# Parsing webpage in Python using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the Web page Source code which I am scraping using Beautiful Soup.

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    1
  </td>
  <td style="cipher1">
    <img class="cipher2" src="http://cipher3.png" alt="cipher4" title="cipher5" />
    <a href="/cipher6" title="cipher6" class="cipher7"><span class="cipher8">t</span>cipher9</a> 
  </td>
  <td>
    112
  </td>
  <td>
    3510
  </td>
```

// Pattern Repeated

```
<tr >
 <td>
        2
 </td>
 <td style="cipher1">
```

I wrote some code using BeautifulSoup but I am getting more results than I want due to multiple occurrences of the pattern.

I have used

```
row1 = soup.find_all('a' ,class_ = "cipher7" )
for row in row1:
    f.write( row['title'] + "\n")
```

But with this I get multiple occurences for 'cipher7' since it is occurring multiple times in the web page.

So the thing I can use this

```
 <td style="cipher1">...
```

since it is unique to the things which I want.

So, How to modify my code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the `td` tag (since you said it is unique) and then find the specified `a`tag from it.

```
all_as = []
rows = soup.find_all('td', {'style':'cipher1'})
for row in rows:
    all_as.append(row.find_all('a', class_ = "cipher7"))
```

Comment: By unique i meant , This <td style="cipher1"> is there before the the line i want .I did what you mentioned but now output is only the first occurence.

Comment: It's showing error! (TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str ''') if i use this 
    f.write( row['title'] + "\n")

Comment: @Jaskamalkainth - Could you show me the complete code? Atleast for this part you are working on. Use gist.github.com, don't paste it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a convenient `select` method which takes a CSS selector as an argument:

```
row = soup.select("td[style=cipher1] > a.cipher7")
```